# Set images for price list via phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have array of data like:

```
$products = array(
   array('path/to/image1', 'name1', 'description1'),
   array('path/to/image2', 'name2', 'description2'),
   array('path/to/image3', 'name3', 'description3'),
   ...
   array('path/to/imageN', 'nameN', 'descriptionN'),
);
```

With this code I generate *.xlsx table:

```
foreach($products as $row) {
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($c, $r, $cell);
        $c++;
    }
    $r++;
}

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('/path/for/save');
```

And after that I get a table with path, name and descriptions. Please help me, because I can't get table where instead of pathes I will get images.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a cell to contain `'path/to/image1'` will do exactly that, set the cell to contain a string value of `'path/to/image1'`.

You need to set images very specifically, as explained in the documentation and shown in the examples:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Image');
$objDrawing->setPath('./path/to/image1.jpg');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

You should also note that MS Excel does not store images **in** a cell. It stores images **overlaying** a cell, so the image may cover several cells

**EDIT**

If you need to convert numeric coordinates such as $row=`3` and $col=`0` to a cell reference like `A3`:

```
$cellReference = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col) . $row;
```

or

```
$cellReference = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)
    ->getCoordinate();
```

Comment: Sure I have seen examples but I have question about this string: $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');   In my example I use setCellValueByColumnAndRow() where I set coordinates, but not absolute identifier of cell. How do I need to set coordinates properly?